# How do I draw Bar-Chart using danielgindi/Charts library with Swift 3.0

Tags: swift, charts, swift3

**Problem Statement :** Unable to run due to some errors in implementation of Bar-Chart using 'danielgindi/Charts library' in swift 3.0 syntax errors.

**Actual Error in Swift 3.0:**

[image]

After correcting above error, it gives another error in next line, as shown below.

[image]

**Coding Stuff:**

```
import Charts

class ChartViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var barChartView: BarChartView!

    var months: [String]!
    var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = []


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
        let unitsSold = [20.0, 4.0, 6.0, 3.0, 12.0, 16.0, 4.0, 18.0, 2.0, 4.0, 5.0, 4.0]
        setChart(dataPoints: months, values: unitsSold)

    }

    func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) {
        barChartView.noDataText = "You need to provide data for the chart."

        for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
            let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), yValues: [values[i]])
            dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
        }

        let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "Units Sold")

        let chartData = BarChartData(xVals: months, dataSet: chartDataSet)

        barChartView.data = chartData
    }
```

Please help me, how do I resolve such errors in swift 3.0

Answer (score 2):

I've had this issue as well.  It was this line here:

```
let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), yValues: [values[i]])
```

You cannot convert dataPoints: [String] to type Double.

My solution was to remove the Double.   Then that did not satisfy my data types, so I made them all of type [Int]  like so:

```
func setChart(dataPoints: [Int], values: [Int]) {

    self.noDataText = "You need to provide data for the chart."

    var dataEntries: [BarChartDataEntry] = []

    for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
        let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: Double(values[i]) )
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)


    }

    let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "Units Sold")
    let chartData = BarChartData(dataSet: chartDataSet)
    self.data = chartData
```

You can convert [Int] to Double, so that fixed my issue.  I changed the variable months: [String] to

```
let months = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

Comment: Thanx for your solution, I already got solution for this problem here  http://stackoverflow.com/a/41741482/5886755 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/41980599/5886755.

Answer (score 2):

```
import UIKit
import Charts

class ViewController: UIViewController, ChartViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var barChartView: BarChartView!
    weak var axisFormatDelegate: IAxisValueFormatter?

    var months: [String]!
    var unitsSold = [Double]()

 override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            barChartView.delegate = self
            axisFormatDelegate = self
            months  = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]
            unitsSold  = [20.0, 54.0, 6.0, 30.0, 92.0, 16.0,114.0]
            setChart(dataPoints: months, values: unitsSold)
        } 
             func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) {

                barChartView.noDataText = "You need to provide data for the chart."

                // Prevent from setting an empty data set to the chart (crashes)
                guard dataPoints.count > 0 else { return }

                var dataEntries = [BarChartDataEntry]()

                for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
                    let entry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: values[i], data: months as AnyObject?)
                    dataEntries.append(entry)
                }

                let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(entries: dataEntries, label: "Units Sold")
                chartDataSet.drawValuesEnabled = false
                chartDataSet.colors = [UIColor.red]
                chartDataSet.colors = [UIColor.lightGray]
                chartDataSet.highlightColor = UIColor.orange.withAlphaComponent(0.3)
                chartDataSet.highlightAlpha = 1
                let chartData = BarChartData(dataSet: chartDataSet)
                barChartView.data = chartData
                let xAxisValue = barChartView.xAxis
                xAxisValue.valueFormatter = axisFormatDelegate

                //   chartDataSet.colors = ChartColorTemplates.colorful()    //multiple colors

                //Animation bars
                barChartView.animate(xAxisDuration: 0.0, yAxisDuration: 1.0, easingOption: .easeInCubic)

                // X axis configurations
                barChartView.xAxis.granularityEnabled = true
                barChartView.xAxis.granularity = 1
                barChartView.xAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = true
                barChartView.xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
                barChartView.xAxis.labelFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15.0)
                barChartView.xAxis.labelTextColor = UIColor.black
                barChartView.xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom

                // Right axis configurations
                barChartView.rightAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
                barChartView.rightAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
                barChartView.rightAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = false

                // Other configurations
                barChartView.highlightPerDragEnabled = false
                barChartView.chartDescription?.text = ""
                barChartView.legend.enabled = false
                barChartView.pinchZoomEnabled = false
                barChartView.doubleTapToZoomEnabled = false
                barChartView.scaleYEnabled = false

                barChartView.drawMarkers = true

                let l = barChartView.legend
                l.horizontalAlignment = .left
                l.verticalAlignment = .bottom
                l.orientation = .horizontal
                l.drawInside = false
                l.form = .circle
                l.formSize = 9
                l.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 11)!
                l.xEntrySpace = 4

                // On tapped bar marker before adding BalloonMarker.swift
                let marker =  BalloonMarker(color: UIColor.orange, font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 13), textColor: UIColor.white, insets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 7.0, left: 7.0, bottom: 15.0, right: 7.0))
                marker.chartView = barChartView
                barChartView.marker = marker
            }
}
    extension ViewController: IAxisValueFormatter {

        func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {
            return months[Int(value)]
        }
    }
```

1. Install pod file
2. Assign `barchartview` class to chart view in `storyboad`
3. Follow `setchart()` method
4. For ballon marker add `BallonMarker.swift` file to your project library    for this file chartsDemo->Components-> BallonMarker.swift

I have implemented a demo for that

This will Support Swift 4.2 and above

Check this link :
[https://github.com/vijay1864/Barchart-Demo-with-Charts-Library](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts)

This Demo was Made with help of danielgindi Charts Library

https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

Comment: Hi Vijay, thanks for your answer. Please note that posting only links isn't appreciate on SO. Please have a look to the help center regarding [good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Very Good Answer

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate month and units sold values as xVal and yVal.

```
  var barChartValues: [BarChartDataEntry] = []

    for (key,val) in self.barChartDataval.enumerated() {

        let xVal = Double(key)
        let yVal = Double(val.cost)
        let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: xVal, y: yVal!)
        barChartValues.append(dataEntry)

    }

    let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: barChartValues, label: "Expenses Summary")
    chartDataSet.colors = [Constants.k_COLORS.BLUE]
    var dataSets = [IChartDataSet]()
    dataSets.append(chartDataSet)

    let chartData = BarChartData(dataSets: dataSets)
    self.barChartView.data = chartData
    self.barChartView.chartDescription?.text = ""

    self.barChartView.animate(xAxisDuration: 2.0, yAxisDuration: 2.0, easingOption: .easeInBounce)
```

Comment: What is self.barChartDataval comes from ?

Answer (score 0):

**For Line chart We can have following**

```
import UIKit
import Charts

class LineChartVC: UIViewController , ChartViewDelegate{
    @IBOutlet var lineChartView: LineChartView!

    var months: [String]!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.lineChartSetUp()

    }

}

    extension LineChartVC{


        func  lineChartSetUp(){

            self.lineChartView.delegate = self
            self.lineChartView.chartDescription?.enabled = false//true

            self.lineChartView.dragEnabled = true
            self.lineChartView.setScaleEnabled(true)
            self.lineChartView.pinchZoomEnabled = true
            self.lineChartView.drawGridBackgroundEnabled = false


            // x-axis limit line
            /*
             let llXAxis = ChartLimitLine(limit: 10.0, label: "Index 10")
             llXAxis.lineWidth = 4.0
             llXAxis.lineDashLengths = [(10.0), (10.0), (0.0)]
             llXAxis.labelPosition = ChartLimitLine.LabelPosition.rightBottom//ChartLimitLabelPositionRightBottom
             llXAxis.valueFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10.0)
             //[_chartView.xAxis addLimitLine:llXAxis];

             self.lineChartView.xAxis.gridLineDashLengths = [10.0, 10.0]
             self.lineChartView.xAxis.gridLineDashPhase = 0.0


             let ll1 = ChartLimitLine(limit: 150.0, label: "Upper Limit")
             ll1.lineWidth = 4.0
             ll1.lineDashLengths = [5.0, 5.0]
             ll1.labelPosition = ChartLimitLine.LabelPosition.rightTop //ChartLimitLabelPositionRightTop
             ll1.valueFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10.0)

             let ll2 = ChartLimitLine(limit: -30.0, label: "Lower Limit")
             ll2.lineWidth = 4.0
             ll2.lineDashLengths = [5.0, 5.0]
             ll2.labelPosition = ChartLimitLine.LabelPosition.rightBottom//ChartLimitLabelPositionRightBottom
             ll2.valueFont = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10.0)

             let leftAxis: YAxis? =  self.lineChartView.leftAxis
             leftAxis?.removeAllLimitLines()

             //         leftAxis?.addLimitLine(ll1)
             //         leftAxis?.addLimitLine(ll2)
             //         leftAxis?.axisMaximum = 200.0
             //         leftAxis?.axisMinimum = -50.0

             //        leftAxis?.axisMaximum = 100.0
             //        leftAxis?.axisMinimum = 0.0
             //
             leftAxis?.gridLineDashLengths = [5.0, 5.0]
             leftAxis?.drawZeroLineEnabled = false
             leftAxis?.drawLimitLinesBehindDataEnabled = true

             self.lineChartView.rightAxis.enabled = false
             //[_chartView.viewPortHandler setMaximumScaleY: 2.f];
             //[_chartView.viewPortHandler setMaximumScaleX: 2.f];
             */
            let marker = BalloonMarker(color: UIColor(white: 180 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0), font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12.0), textColor: UIColor.white, insets: UIEdgeInsetsMake(8.0, 8.0, 20.0, 8.0))
            marker.chartView = self.lineChartView
            marker.minimumSize = CGSize(width: 80.0, height: 40.0)
            self.lineChartView.marker = marker
            self.lineChartView.legend.form = Legend.Form(rawValue: 5)!

            months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
            let unitsSold = [20.0, 4.0, 6.0, 3.0, 12.0, 16.0, 4.0, 18.0, 2.0, 4.0, 5.0, 4.0]

            self.setChart(months, values: unitsSold)

        }



        func setChart(_ dataPoints: [String], values: [Double]) {

            var dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []

            for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {

                let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(x:Double(i) , y: values[i])
                dataEntries.append(dataEntry)

            }
            print(dataEntries )

            let data = LineChartData()
            let ds1 = LineChartDataSet(values: dataEntries, label: "Units Sold")
            ds1.colors = [UIColor.red]
            data.addDataSet(ds1)
            self.lineChartView.data = data



        }


        func chartValueSelected(chartView: ChartViewBase, entry: ChartDataEntry, dataSetIndex: Int, highlight: Highlight) {
            //        print("\(entry.value) in \(months[dataSetIndex])")
            print(entry )
        }




    }
```